# change multiple image on hover: jquery/css/html

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is what I'm trying to do. I have a table of thumbnail images and a larger image in the middle of the table.

```
img01 |  img02 | img03 | img04

img05 | `*BIG IMAGE *` | img06

img07 | `*BIG IMAGE *` | img08

img09 | `*BIG IMAGE *` | img10

img11 | `*BIG IMAGE *` | img12

img13 |  img14 | img15 | img16
```

When you hover over the thumbnail images:

1) the opacity of thumbnail changes from 50% to 100% AND
2) BIG IMAGE will change to 400x400 image for img01 (i.e. img01_400x400.jpg)

When you also click on thumbnail image, the "BIG IMAGE" will change to 400x400 image

I was able to get coding to work properly up to step (1) where the opacity of thumbnail images change on hover.

Does anyone know how to accomplish step (2)? Any help greatly appreciated.
I've been stuck on this for a few days.

Mike

**Added code snippets from comments**

This is what I have so far for css:

```
.hovereffect img { opacity:0.5; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50); -moz-opacity:0.5; -khtml-opacity:0.5; } 
.hovereffect:hover img { opacity:1.0; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100); -moz-opacity:1.0; -khtml-opacity:1; }
```

This is a snippet for piece of code for one of the thumbnails:

```
<td align="center">
    <a class="hovereffect" onblur="try {parent.deselectBloggerImageGracefully();} catch(e) {}" href="/ad01.php"><img style="cursor: pointer; width: 66px; height: 66px;" src="/images/ad_01d.png" alt="Hover Effect" id="" border="0" /></a>
</td>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you're working with, or a simplified mockup so we can have some understanding of what you're after

Comment: This is what I have so far for css:
    .hovereffect img {
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity:0.5;
    }
    .hovereffect:hover img {
    opacity:1.0;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity:1.0;
    -khtml-opacity:1;
    }

Comment: This is a snippet for piece of code for one of the thumbnails
    <td align="center"><a class="hovereffect" onblur="try                {parent.deselectBloggerImageGracefully();} catch(e) {}" href="/ad01.php"><img style="cursor: pointer; width: 66px; height: 66px;" src="/images/ad_01d.png" alt="Hover Effect" id="" border="0" /></a></td>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good fade effect. It fades out an image on top of a background image. Hopefully it can get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gYyBL/

HTML:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/vdDQgb.jpg" hoverImg="http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg" bigImg="http://i.imgur.com/Epl4db.jpg">
<img src="" style"display:none" id="big">
```

JS:

```
$('body').find('*[hoverImg]').each(function(index){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.wrap('<div>')  ;   
    $this.parent().css('width',$this.width()) ; 
    $this.parent().css('height',$this.width());
    $('#big').attr('src',$this.attr('hoverImg')); <-- this will show the big image;
    $this.parent().css('background-image',"url(" + $this.attr('hoverImg')+")")
        $this.hover(function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',.01)    
        },function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',1)             
        })                    
});
```

​

Comment: Already got that part covered. Need help figuring out how to change second image on hover discussed in step (2).